# Error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save multiple records in the database, the data is stored correctly in the list, but when I press the button to save into the database, it does not work.

Having only one record in the lists and pressing the button2 nothing happens, but having more than 2 records in the list and pressing the button2 the program crashes with the following error code:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'roll' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

What is my mistake?

Variables:

```
    int p = 0;
    string x = "";
    decimal xx = 0;
    string v = "";
    decimal vv = 0;
    string f = "";
    decimal ff = 0;
    decimal pp = 0;
    List<int> piece = new List<int>();
    List<string> protein = new List<string>();
    List<string> vegetable = new List<string>();
    List<string> wrapped = new List<string>();
    List<decimal> piecePrice = new List<decimal>();
    List<decimal> proteinPrice = new List<decimal>();
    List<decimal> vegetablePrice = new List<decimal>();
    List<decimal> wrappedPrice = new List<decimal>();
```

Button Click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        piece.Add(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        protein.Add(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        vegetable.Add(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString());
        wrapped.Add(comboBox4.SelectedValue.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < piece.Count(); i++)
        {
            var p = piece[piece.Count - 1];
            var h = protein[protein.Count - 1];
            var v = vegetable[vegetable.Count - 1];
            var f = wrapped[ wrapped.Count - 1];

            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                 piecePrice.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(context.piece.SingleOrDefault(x => x.quantity == p)?.price));
                proteinPrice.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(context.protein.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == h)?.price));
                vegetablePrice.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(context.vegetable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == h)?.price));
                wrappedPrice.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(context. wrapped.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == f)?.price));
            }
        }
}
```

Save button click handler:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<rolls> rolls = new List<rolls>();

        for (int i = 0; i < piece.Count(); i++)
        {
            p = piece[i];
            pp = piecePrice[i];
            x = protein[i];
            v = vegetable[i];
            f =  wrapped[i];
            xx = proteinPrice[i];
            vv = vegetablePrice[i];
            ff =  wrappedPrice[i];

            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                rolls.Add(new rolls()
                    {
                        quantity = p,
                        quantity_price = pp,
                        protein = x,
                        protein_price = xx,
                        vegetable = v,
                        vegetable_price = vv,
                        wrapped = f,
                        wrapped_price = ff
                    });

                context.AddRange(rolls);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

Rolls table:

```
 public class rolls
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int rollId { get; set; }

        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal quantity_price { get; set; }
        public string protein { get; set; }

        public decimal protein_price { get; set; }
        public string vegetable { get; set; }

        public decimal vegetable_price { get; set; }
        public string wrapped { get; set; }

        public decimal wrapped_price { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: The exception "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'roll' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" means that you tried to insert an actual value into a column that is auto-generated.

Comment: aggregate table roll ,,There are tables, protein, vegetable, and wrapped charts where I get the name and pricing data to save to Rolls.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that you want to insert the same values with your Rolls list. Remove "using(){...}" code lines from for loop. Just prepare your list for the inserting process. When for loop ended you can insert your list data with AddRange functions.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<rolls> rolls = new List<rolls>();
    for (int i = 0; i < piece.Count(); i++)
    {
        p = piece[i];
        pp = piecePrice[i];
        x = protein[i];
        v = vegetable[i];
        f =  wrapped[i];
        xx = proteinPrice[i];
        vv = vegetablePrice[i];
        ff =  wrappedPrice[I];

        rolls.Add(new rolls()
                {
                    quantity = p,
                    quantity_price = pp,
                    protein=x,
                    protein_price=xx,
                    vegetable=v,
                    vegetable_price=vv,
                    wrapped=f,
                     wrapped_price = ff

        });
    }

    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
       context.AddRange(rolls);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The other option is you want to insert a record with an identity column (an ID or one of the columns your Rolls table) but this column cannot be insertable. Please check it.